# URI Format for Creating an Airflow S3 Connection via Environment Variables

Tags: amazon-s3, airflow

I've read the documentation for [creating an Airflow Connection via an environment variable](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/connection/index.html#creating-a-connection-with-environment-variables) and am using Airflow v1.10.6 with Python3.5 on Debian9.

The linked documentation above shows an example S3 connection of `s3://accesskey:secretkey@S3` From that, I defined the following environment variable:

`AIRFLOW_CONN_AWS_S3=s3://#MY_ACCESS_KEY#:#MY_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY#@S3`

And the following function

```py
def download_file_from_S3_with_hook(key, bucket_name):
    """Get file contents from S3"""
    hook = airflow.hooks.S3_hook.S3Hook('aws_s3')
    obj = hook.get_key(key, bucket_name)
    contents = obj.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
    return contents
```

However, when I invoke that function I get the following error:

```
Using connection to: id: aws_s3.
    Host: #MY_ACCESS_KEY#,
    Port: None,
    Schema: #MY_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY#,
    Login: None,
    Password: None,
    extra: {}
ERROR - Unable to locate credentials
```

It appears that when I format the URI according to Airflow's documentation it's sitting the access key as the host and the secret access key as the schema.

It's clearly reading the environment variable as it has the correct `conn_id`. It also has the correct values for my access key and secret, it's just parcing it under the wrong field.

When I set the connection in the UI, the function works if I set `Login` to my access key and `Password` to my token. So how am I formatting my environment variable URI wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the issue, `s3://accesskey:secretkey@S3` is the correct format, the problem was my `aws_secret_access_key` had a special character in it and had to be urlencoded. That fixed everything.

Comment: @cybolobster: Did you encode just the secret key or the whole connection string?

Comment: Just the secret key. In general, the values and only the values need to be encoded

Comment: This worked for me as well.  I added one more env variable: AIRFLOW_VAR_AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1